# Skipping a range of values in for loop C#

Tags: c#, .net, loops, object, logic

I'm trying to cycle through chars in a string.

```
string cycleMe = "Hi StackOverflow! Here is my string."
```

However, I want to skip over certain ranges of indexes. The ranges I want to skip over are stored in a List of objects, delims.

```
List<Delim> delims = delimCreator();
```

To retrieve each starting index and ending index for a range, I have to write a loop that accesses each "delim":

```
delims[0].getFirstIndex() //results in, say, index 2
delims[0].getLastIndex() //results in, say, index 4

delims[1].getFirstIndex() //results in, say, index 5
delims[1].getLastIndex() //results in, say, index 7
```

(there can be infinitely many "delim" objects in play)

If the above were my list, I'd want to print the string cycleMe, but skip all the chars between 2 and 4 (inclusive) and 5 and 7 (inclusive).

Expected output using the numbers above:

```
HiOverflow! Here is my string.
```

Here is the code I have written so far. It loops far more often than I'd expect (it loops ~x2 the number of characters in the string). Thanks in advance! =)

```
  List<Delim> delims = delimAggregateInator(displayTextRaw);

  for (int x = 0; x < cycleMe.Length;x++){

    for (int i = 0; i < delims.Count; i++){

      if (!(x >= delims[i].getFirstIndex() && x <= delims[i].getLastIndex())){


          Debug.Log("test");


      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "skip"? Should the string "abcdefgh" be trimmed to something like "abcfgh" or would you like to have spaces instead like "abc  fgh"?

Comment: @JustShadow Either/or is good.

Comment: To clarify this question, add your input, expected output, and your code's output. Show what you want to achieve but failed.

Comment: @greenorangesan, I've updated my answer below. Please take a look.

Comment: Are you a Java developer, by chance? What's with `.getFirstIndex()` when the idiomatic code in C# would be `.FirstIndex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by skipping you meant you want to omit those characters from the original string. If that is the case, you can try Aggregate extension method like below.

```
string result = delims.Aggregate<Delim, string>(cycleMe, (str, d) => cycleMe = cycleMe.Remove(d.FirstIndex, (d.LastIndex - d.FirstIndex) + 1));
```

Make sure that the delim list is in the proper order.

Answer (score 1):

Solution might be converting the string to char array, replacing the desired parts to spaces, and converting the output back to string.

Here is the modified version of your code:

```
string cycleMe = "Hi StackOverflow! Here is my string."
var charArray = cycleMe.ToCharArray(); // Converting to char array

List<Delim> delims = delimAggregateInator(displayTextRaw);
for (int x = 0; x < cycleMe.Length;x++){
  for (int i = 0; i < delims.Count; i++){
    // ORIGINAL: if (!(x >= delims[i].getFirstIndex() && x <= delims[i].getLastIndex())){
    if (x >= delims[i].getFirstIndex() && x <= delims[i].getLastIndex()){
       Debug.Log("test");
       charArray[x] = ' '; // Replacing the item with space
    }
}

string output = new string(charArray); // Converting back to string
```

P.S. This is probably not the most optimal solution but at least it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You should use LINQ for that

```
    struct Delim
    {
        public int First { get; set; }
        public int Last { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cycleMe = "Hi StackOverflow! Here is my string.";

        var delimns = new List<Delim> { new Delim { First=2, Last=4}, new Delim { First = 5, Last = 7 } };

        var cut = cycleMe.Where((c, i) => 
           !delimns.Any(d => i >= d.First && i <= d.Last));

        Console.WriteLine(new string(cut.ToArray());
    }
```

That means I am basically only selecting letters, at positions which are not part of any cutting range.

Also: Fix your naming. A delimiter is a character, not a position (numeric)